# Dynamically choosing drawable

Tags: android, eclipse, dynamic, wallpaper

I want the user to select a wallpaper and I'll set it as the android wallpaper.
I'm currently using this line:

```
myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.a1);
```

Problem is it's not dynamic and I want to change the chosen image to `R.drawable.a2`,`R.drawable.a3`,`R.drawable.a4`, etc based on the number I got.
So if I have int chosenPicNum=3 I want to create the string "`R.drawable.a`"+3 and then call   `myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.a3);`

But I can't do it. The error is eclipse reads it as a string and not a resource.
Currently here's the closest I've gotten:

```
String imageResource="R.drawable.a"+chosenPicNum) ;
```

So imageResource in this case is String type "`R.drawable.a3`" but I want it to be R.drawable.a3.

Thank you for your help!!

Dvir, ambitious 20 year old :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getIdentifier() like this:

```
public final static String PACKAGE = "..."; // insert your package name

private int getDrawable(String name) {
    return getId(name, "drawable");
}

private int getId(String name, String type) {
    return getResources().getIdentifier(name, type, PACKAGE);
}
```

Access the method using:

```
myWallpaperManager.setResource(getDrawable("a" + chosenPicNum));
```

Comment: mmm it always returns 0. Here's what my print statemants gave me:
                value of string a is R.drawable.a2
  value of R.drawable.a1 is 2130837504
  value of getDrawable(a) is 0

Comment: Fixed. Not supposed to pass R.drawable (getIdentifier does that).

Answer (score 0):

As you use resources, you already know their number and names. So use an array:

```
int[] ids = new int[] {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, };
```

And when you have your chosenNumPic (assuming it's 0 based):

```
if (chosenNumPic >= 0 && chosenNumPic < ids.length) {
    myWallpaperManager.setResource(ids[chosenNumPic]);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: He asked for a dynamic solution. This is static.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("your_drawable_name"), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
imageview.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```